# Python setLevel on StreamHandler does not work

Tags: python, logging

I have setup logging as follows:

```
def setUp():

    LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(name)s %(message)s'
    #LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(name)s %(message)s'

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=LOG_FORMAT)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(LOG_FORMAT)

    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(ch)

    LOG_FILENAME = 'file.log'
    fh = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILENAME, 'w')
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(fh)
```

However, the console still shows `DEBUG` messages. Am I missing something here?

Note that setting the level to `ERROR` on `fh` works fine.

Comment: I guess messages are propagated to the root logger for which you set log level to DEBUG. This together with the fact that root logger by default outputs to console (guessing) would give what you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to remove the call to `logging.basicConfig`. That function adds another `logging.StreamHandler` that probably is the one that is printing the messages you don't want to be printed.

To check this you can take a look at the `handlers` attribute for the root logger (it's a list with all the handlers being used) and verify how many `logging.StreamHandlers` there are. Also, probably the message with level set to `logging.ERROR` are printed twice because of the two `logging.StreamHandler`s.

My final advice is avoid using `logging.basicConfig` if you're going to explicitly configure the handlers in the code.

Edit: Just for completeness, the source code of `logging.BasicConfig` is as follows:

```
if len(root.handlers) == 0:
    filename = kwargs.get("filename")
    if filename:
        mode = kwargs.get("filemode", 'a')
        hdlr = FileHandler(filename, mode)
    else:
        stream = kwargs.get("stream")
        hdlr = StreamHandler(stream)
    fs = kwargs.get("format", BASIC_FORMAT)
    dfs = kwargs.get("datefmt", None)
    fmt = Formatter(fs, dfs)
    hdlr.setFormatter(fmt)
    root.addHandler(hdlr)
    level = kwargs.get("level")
    if level is not None:
        root.setLevel(level)
```

where you can see that unless `filename` is passed, a `logging.StreamHandler` is created.

Answer (score 2):

From Python docs on [logging.basicConfig](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html):

> Does basic configuration for the logging system by creating a
>   StreamHandler with a default Formatter and adding it to the root
>   logger.

As you set debug level of root logger to `logging.DEBUG` and you didn't switched off forwarding messages up to the root logger your DEBUG messages get logged by this StreamHandler created by `basicConfig`